# Compile Error in C: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c, gcc

I'm brand new to C, (like started 2 days ago) and I am having compile issues due to syntax but the error messages I am getting from gcc are not helping me much. I compiled as follows: `gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic line.c`

The whole thing is a simple introductory exercise fro my 101 class. The values are just tested against each other to make sure they were assigned properly in a line_test.c file. But before I can address that one's compile issues I need to address this file.

Here is my code:

```
#include "line.h"

struct line2d create_line2d (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    struct line2d line;
    line.x1=1;
    line.y1=2;
    line.x2=3;
    line.y2=4;
    return line;
}
```

and the line.h code:

```
#ifndef line
#define line

struct line2d {
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
};

struct line2d create_line2d(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

#endif
```

and here is the error it throws

```
line.c: In function ‘create_line2d’:
line.c:5: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token
line.c:6: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token
line.c:7: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token
line.c:8: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token
line.c:9: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
```

Comment: And what is `line2d`'s definition?

Comment: [WorksForMe](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yQFKj$0)... please provide more details of your code and compilation process.

Comment: It looks most like you are editing a different file than you are building - check that your directories match and that everything lines up build-wise, etc.

Comment: The directories match. All the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @Mankarse: returning in function a local variable in C which isn't static and no gcc warning? what am I missing?

Comment: @jack, returning structures (and passing them as parameters) by value is supported by C.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I don't knew it. I'd in my mind that the variable shall be static because of its lifetime end up when function ends. So,making the returned variable by the function an address to a "dead variable" and therefore,invalid value.

Comment: @Jack, it works the same as an `int`, for example.  The entire structure gets returned by value (read: copied).  If the OP were returning a *pointer* to the structure, there'd be a problem.

Comment: You can also get that error if you mistakenly specify the variable type when you're calling the function, I just saw it.  Def: void somefunc(int foo) calling: somefunc(init bar).  Take out the var types on the 2nd one and it works.  I was sleepy.

Answer (score 9):

In the header file you defined `line` as nothing. In the C file you use it and the preprocessor replaces every instance of the word `line` with nothing. So basically, you're trying to compile:

```
struct line2d create_line2d (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    struct line2d line;
    .x1=1;
    .y1=2;
    .x2=3;
    .y2=4;
    return ;
}
```

Obviously, that won't work :)

You should always use some string that won't ever be used anywhere else for the `#ifdef` guard. Something like `LINE__H___` would a better choice.

```
#ifndef LINE__H___
#define LINE__H___

struct line2d {
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
};

struct line2d create_line2d(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

#endif//!LINE__H___
```

In more recent versions of common compilers, you can use `#pragma once` and avoid the entire name collision issue completely.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but `___LINE__H___` is a very bad choice.  Identfiers starting with two underscores or an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation.  Use `LINE_H` or something like that.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I get it. I did see that the definition had to be `#ifndef symbol name` somewhere

Comment: @Inisheer, I guess for the reason I mentioned?

Comment: Not too many people follow the rules and `LINE_H` is too plain and might be used as constant. That's why they invented `#pragma once` :) And it seems recent version of GCC support it (4.6.2+).

Comment: @kichik, why deliberately make non-standard compliant code when you don't have to?

Comment: @Inisheer - wasn't me.  Just guessing.  Having been burned by an errant `__DEBUG__` once or twice, I'm particularly sensitive to the issue.

Comment: @Carl Norum, because of personal experience. `LINE_H` is very likely to have the same issue.

Comment: @kichik - LINE_H is *guaranteed* to *not* be used by the implementation.  What are you saying?  `LINE_H___________` is fine, if you want.  Just don't put the `__` in front.

Comment: I'm saying a large codebase that possibly uses a lot of libraries might also randomly use `LINE_H` for another constant. `LINE_H_____` is a possible solution and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @kichik just append a UUID after `LINE_H`, and the random use problem will be solved. Like this: `LINE_H_C5C91323_870C_4010_A418_70DC953F8AA2`.

Answer (score 2):

You've done `#define line` in your header - so the preprocessor replaces `line` with "" (nothing).

So your C code is:

```
.x1=1;
```

Probably the best thing is to make the inclusion protection define something more unique: `INCLUDE_GUARD_LINE_H`, perhaps. In any case, it should be upper case.